# Adding Items to a dropdownlist works in code but I can't see it in the resulting page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

This code get's called and all objects are set and the code works when I trace it it goes through the loop adds time items to the combo start and end and I see it trace it's way though.  The trace also shows a valid amount of items as per calculated. But when I look at the asp website after running this code, the dropdownlist called (DropStartTime and DropEndTime) I use don't get their values added in their items.

I hope it was clear.

Public Sub GenerateTime(RowIndex As Integer)

```
    Dim ComboStart As DropDownList
    Dim ComboEnd As DropDownList
    Dim ItemList As ListItem
    Dim TimeInterval As Integer
    Dim IntervalleCalcul As Integer
    Dim NombreIntervalles As Integer
    Dim HeureCalcule As String
    Dim Laps As Integer

    GridDetails.EditIndex = RowIndex
    GridDetails.DataBind()

    ComboStart = GridDetails.Rows(RowIndex).FindControl("DropStartTime")
    ComboEnd = GridDetails.Rows(RowIndex).FindControl("DropEndTime")

    If Not IsNothing(ComboStart) Or Not IsNothing(ComboEnd) Then

        ComboStart.Items.Clear()
        ComboEnd.Items.Clear()
        ' --------------------------------------------
        '  DETERMINATION DES PARAMETRES D'INTERVALLES
        ' --------------------------------------------
        Select Case TimeInterval
            Case 5
                IntervalleCalcul = 12
                Laps = 5
            Case 10
                IntervalleCalcul = 6
                Laps = 10
            Case 15
                IntervalleCalcul = 4
                Laps = 15
            Case 30
                IntervalleCalcul = 2
                Laps = 30
            Case 60
                IntervalleCalcul = 1
                Laps = 60
            Case Else
                IntervalleCalcul = 4
                Laps = 15

        End Select

        NombreIntervalles = 24 * IntervalleCalcul
        HeureCalcule = "00:00"
        ItemList = New ListItem
        ItemList.Text = HeureCalcule
        ItemList.Value = HeureCalcule

        ComboStart.Items.Add(ItemList)
        ComboEnd.Items.Add(ItemList)
        For Compteur = 1 To NombreIntervalles - 1
            HeureCalcule = CalculerTemps(HeureCalcule, Laps)
            ItemList = New ListItem
            ItemList.Text = HeureCalcule
            ItemList.Value = HeureCalcule
            ComboStart.Items.Add(ItemList)
            ComboEnd.Items.Add(ItemList)
        Next Compteur

    End If

End Sub
```

now this code excutes and goes in the loop 96 times as expected, and adds the items to both combos, in code.  however when I go to the asp website after calling this, the combo boxes don't have any items added to them, I would think that the should being this function is called.  No errors are of course reported either.

Help :)

Answer (score 0):

Bit wordy for a comment, not really a great answer though - since you give no information on Page_Load and Postbacks, this is only a starting best guess.

There's a high chance you may not be factoring in control creation in relation to ASP.NET. What I mean is, if your code is anything like the following, then the dropdown boxes the code is correctly populating are actually destroyed and new ones created on load/postback.

1. Load page with dropdown boxes. (Load_1)
2. Press button to call GenerateTime sub
3. GenerateTime sub runs and works fine.
4. Page is posted back.
5. Page_Load runs again. (Load_2)
6. The dropdowns created on the page as a result of Load_2 are NOT the same that GenerateTime populated when it ran, they have been basically destroyed and recreated.

You may need to factor in when controls are created and how you handle postbacks. Possibly look into wrapping certain code in Page_Load around

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack
```

Hope this is of some help.

EDIT - noticed they are dynamic controls. This link may assist.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

Comment: Thank you for your quick response I appreciate it a whole lot. I also have a button and a calendar control that are gridview edititems and any operations I do with those seem to be working fine, just the dropdownlists I use don't wanna work properly. I have no page_load code I have in the rowediting event the code: ' If Not IsPostBack Then
            GridDetails.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
            GridDetails.DataBind()

            GenerateTime(GridDetails.EditIndex)
        End If
' and that's it. I've done this before but it was with a C1ComboBox but hey logic is logic no? :)

Comment: I've always steered clear of Gridviews where possible. I notice you're creating dropdown objects then finding the correct one in the gridrow - it's not simply a case of missing Gridview.Refresh or something similar is it? (just a thought)

Comment: it might be i'll have to overall my refreshes to be sure but why would I need to do it for things like dropdownlists and not have to do it for the calendar control?  shouldn't all this be the same? Now aside the gridview control is there another, freely available gridview like control? It has to be free as I don't have the finances to buy one right now?

Comment: Did you try databind() on grid or dropdown before your End If

Comment: I did just now, to no avail. I don't get it, I have other controls I do things to on that grid, only these two dropdownlists are not doing their thing. lol